# Davinci Resolve - Blanking Fill not working properly

Tags: davinci-resolve

I'm fairly new to resolve. All I'm trying to achieve is to eliminate the black bars when importing a 16:9 video to a 4:5 format. However, the blanking fill only seems to affect the video area and not the whole frame. I've tried to do the same on a vertical video in a new project and the same thing was happening. I've also tried creating a new compound clip, sadly it also had no effect. I will attach a screenshot of a clip and fx window and send more information if needed. Rn, I am simply lost.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated the program and the issue evaporated. Question RESOLVEd, get it?
sorry